# Bash command to archive files daily based on date added

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, tar, backup-strategies

I have a suite of scripts that involve downloading files from a remote server and then parsing them.  Each night, I would like to create an archive of the files downloaded that day.

Some constraints are:

- Downloading from a Windows server to an Ubuntu server.
- Inability to delete files on the remote server.
- Require the date *added* to the local directory, **not** the date the file was created.
- I have deduplication running at the downloading stage; however, (using ncftp), the check involves comparing the remote and local directories.  A strategy is to create a new folder each day, download files into it and then tar it sometime after midnight.  A problem arises in that the first scheduled download on the new day will grab ALL files on the remote server because the new local folder is empty.

Because of the constraints, I considered simply archiving files based on "date added" to a central folder.  This works very well using a Mac because HFS+ stores extended metadata such as date created and date added.  So I can combine a tar command with something like below:

```
 mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemDateAdded -raw *.xml | \ 
 xargs -0 -I {} echo {} | \ 
 sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | \
```

but there doesn't seem to be an analogue under linux (at least not with EXT4 that I am aware of).

I am open to any form of solution to get around doubling up files into a subsequent day.  The end result should be an archives directory full of tar.gz files looking something like:

```
files_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the method that is used to backup the files, the modified or changed date should reflect the time it was copied - for example if you used cp -p  to back them up, the modified date would not change but the changed date would reflect the time of copy.

You can get this information using the `stat` command:

```
stat <filename>
```

which will return the following (along with other file related info not shown):

```
Access: 2016-05-28 20:35:03.153214170 -0400
Modify: 2016-05-28 20:34:59.456122913 -0400
Change: 2016-05-29 01:39:52.070336376 -0400
```

This output is from a file that I copied using cp -p at the time shown as 'change'.

You can get just the change time by calling stat with a specified format:

```
stat -c '%z' <filename>
2016-05-29 01:39:56.037433640 -0400
```

or with capital Z for that time in seconds since epoch. You could combine that with the date command to pull out just the date (or use grep, etc)

```
date -d "`stat -c '%z' <filename>" -I
2016-05-29
```

The command `find` can be used to find files by time frame, in this case using the flags `-cmin` 'changed minutes', `-mmin` 'modified minutes', or unlikely, `-amin` 'accessed minutes'. The sequence of commands to get the minutes since midnight is a little ugly, but it works.

We have to pass find an argument of "minutes since a file was last changed" (or modified, if that criteria works). So first you have to calculate the minutes since midnight, then run find.

```
min_since_mid=$(echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(date -d "(date -I) 0" +%s) )) / 60 | bc)
```

Unrolling that a bit:

- `$(date +%s)`   == seconds since epoch until 'now'
- `"(date -I) 0"` == todays date in format "YYYY-MM-DD 0" with 0 indicating 0 seconds into the day
- `$(date -d "(date -I 0" +%s))` == seconds from epoch until today at midnight
- Then we (effectively) echo ( $now - $midnight ) / 60 to bc to convert the results into minutes.

The find call is passed the minutes since midnight with a leading '-' indicating up to X minutes ago. A'+' would indicate X minutes or more ago.

```
find /path/to/base/folder -cmin -"$min_since_mid"
```

#### The actual answer

Finally to create a tgz archive of files in the given directory (and subdirectories) that have been changed since midnight today, use these two commands:

```
min_since_mid=$(echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(date -d "(date -I) 0" +%s) )) / 60 | bc)

find /path/to/base/folder -cmin -"${min_since_mid:-0}" -print0 -exec tar czvf /path/to/new/tarball.tgz {} +
```

The -print0 argument to find tells it to delimit the files with a null string which will prevent issues with spaces in names, among other things.

The only thing I'm not sure on is you should use the changed time (-cmin), the modified time (-mmin) or the accessed time (-amin). Take a look at your backup files and see which field accurately reflects the date/time of the backup - I would think changed time, but I'm not certain.

Update: changed `-"$min_since_mid"` to  -"${min_since_mid:-0}" so that if min_since_mid isn't set you won't error out with invalid argument - you just won't get any results. You could also surround the find with an if statement to block the call if that variable isn't set properly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to compose such a detailed response.  I have tried the actual answer with the appropriate changes and I keep hitting this wall: `(standard_in) 1: syntax error; find: invalid argument "-print0" to "-cmin"  If I change cmin to mmin it returns the same.  If I drop the first $ in min_since_mid, the first error goes away but the second persists.  Might you have a suggestion or perhaps an idea how to work around these errors?

Comment: Are you sure you are using -print0 with a zero, not the letter O? What version of find do you have, and is it aliased to anything (results of `find --version`, `type find`, `which find`). I just checked that the code runs fine on find version 4.51 (centos 7) and 4.6 (fedora 24 beta). Check if $min_since_mid is being set to anything. Run the first command; then `echo $min_since_mid`  if $min_since_mid is empty, then it will fail exactly the way you are getting.

Comment: I should have said 'fail in a similar way'; the word 'exactly' is incorrect. Let me know what you find out and I'll try to fix it. Also - try running just `find /path/to/base/folder -cmin -"$min_since_mid"` and see if that works correctly.

Comment: I broke down the echo command a bit more, I think my shell was having trouble subtracting the dates.  The $min_since_mid returns 611, so that is solid.  If I try the find command it returns nothing.  Here are the details of the find: find version 4.4.2, /usr/bin/find, /usr/bin/find

Comment: Apologies, very stupid mistake.  Rather than run with calculated dates in my folder name (to search for todays date automatically) I was using the hardcoded date from my testing last night and that was before midnight, so of course it was returning nothing.  I just ran it with the proper folder reference and it found everything and created a tgz.  I am going to unzip it to test but I think this solved all my problems. EDIT: Just confirmed that all the files are there in the tgz.  Thank you very much for your help and detailed explanation.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did the cmin or mmin - or both - capture the time it was copied?

Comment: I just tried both and did a diff mmin.tgz cmin.tgz and there was no difference between the two.  So it definitely captures the information.  I wonder then if cmin = mmin only based on being created in the local dir (akin to date added on Mac OSX) rather than the actual date created?

Comment: Neither are creation date necessarily; that can be retrieved with stat -c '%w' but most file systems don't store it. Depending on how you copy/archive the files, the modified time stamp may or may not be updated. The changed should be updated regardless, so it's the safer choice.

Comment: thanks again for the clarification.  I tried the %w and sure enough it was empty.  Perhaps one day EXT will incorporate extended metadata like HFS+ does.